# Convert MFC radio button into static text

Tags: mfc, radio-button, static-text

Is there any way to convert a MFC radio button into a plain CStatic text (i.e. remove the radio)? If so, how?
I've only been able to find out how to convert radio buttons to other types of buttons, but this isn't really what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't convert it. What you can do is create both a radio button and a static in the same place. Use ShowWindow to make one of them visible and one of them invisible.